# Typescript does not allow an extended class promise to be the return type of an async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have got a class that is extended from the global Promise class and should have some additional normal and async functions.
The normal functions like "init" are working but the async one like "doSomething" are not.

It always throws the following typescript error:

> The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type.

I don't know why it isn't working. Here is the code I'm working on.

```js
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    private somedata = {};

    constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
        super(executor);
    }

    public static init<T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): MyPromise<T> {
        return new MyPromise(executor);
    }

    public async doSomething(fnc: () => Promise<number>): MyPromise<T> {
        this.somedata = await fnc();

        return this;
    }
}
```

Update: @Evert was right, it was a XY problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to extend Promise? Seems like an XY problem...

Comment: @elclanrs There are *plenty* of reasons to want a non-standard Promise: cancelling, timeouts, deferreds, etc. How many times do you write `Promise.race(new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, timeout)), fetch(someURL));`

Comment: @JaredSmith I cannot find many reasons to do that by extending Promise. You could probably just use a thenabe (an object with `then` method).

Comment: @elclanrs fair enough.

Comment: In your `doSomething()` example, you could just implement that function without `async/await` and then you could return your own promise sublcass.  Back-in-the-day, we used to know how to do that!

Comment: Just wondering out loud here, is this a justification for adding custom methods to the built-in promise? Or is that still out-of-bounds?

Comment: @JaredSmith I tend to prefer composition over inheritance, as composition doesn't limit you by forcing you to obey the rules of polymorphism, whereas with inheritance, your subclass must be able to be used exactly like the base class, wherever an implementation expects an interface implementing the base class.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can't tell if that was sarcasm but if you were serious, I'd at least suggest using unique symbols as the properties for your custom methods to avoid any possibility of collision.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Not meant as sarcasm.  If you want a method like a timeout on a lot of your promises and want to use `async` functions, it seems like the only convenient, simple way to do it is to add methods to the built-in promise prototype.  Otherwise, you have to constantly wrap system-returned promises to get them to be the kind of promise you want which is messy.  I know there are reasons to NOT path non-standard methods onto built-in objects, but there does seem to be a case for it in this case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - How would composition be used to solve this problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 well you have my hands tied after explicitly mentioning `you have to constantly wrap system-returned promises to get them to be the kind of promise you want which is messy`. But the first thing that comes to mind is an extension-method interface with a signature like `let myExtension = (...myParams) => (promise) => ...` which, with certain versions of the proposal for the pipeline operator, could be used like `somePromise |> myExtension(...myArgs)`

Comment: @JaredSmith Extending promise is not helpful when promise is nested as enclosing promise may not be of the same type. Timeout can be achieved using simple promise with set timeout, for cancellation one must use AbortController.signal as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `async` function returns a built-in Promise. Changing the return type of the function does not alter this.

So you must change `MyPromise<T>` to `Promise<T>`, or not use `async`.

You can of course still return MyPromise, it just means that you need to stop using async.

Comment: I thought the point of using await in an async function was to get the value returned by the promise. TypeScript really complicates some things rather than simplifies them. So how can we get TypeScript to stop changing the result type between `.then()` and `.catch()`?

Comment: @Suncat2000 not sure what you mean. Maybe open a new question?

Comment: I tried to assign a variable in a `.then()` and assign a default in a `.catch()` but when I tried to return it, TypeScript it a type of `never`. I got around it by wrapping the code in another async-await function and returning values inside the `.then()` and `.catch()` after the promise was fulfilled. It still returns another promise, but one I can attach  a `.then()` clause to and use the value immediately. Thanks for your insight.